# accelerate comparing dictionary keys and values to strings in list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

Sorry if this is trivial I'm still learning but I have a list of dictionaries that looks as follow:

```
[{'1102': ['00576', '00577', '00578', '00579', '00580', '00581']},
 {'1102': ['00582', '00583', '00584', '00585', '00586', '00587']},
 {'1102': ['00588', '00589', '00590', '00591', '00592', '00593']},
 {'1102': ['00594', '00595', '00596', '00597', '00598', '00599']},
 {'1102': ['00600', '00601', '00602', '00603', '00604', '00605']}
 ...]
```

it contains ~89000 dictionaries. And I have a list containing 4473208 paths. example:

```
['/****/**/******_1102/00575***...**0CT.csv',
'/****/**/******_1102/00575***...**1CT.csv',
'/****/**/******_1102/00575***...**2CT.csv',
'/****/**/******_1102/00575***...**3CT.csv',
'/****/**/******_1102/00575***...**4CT.csv',
'/****/**/******_1102/00578***...**1CT.csv',
'/****/**/******_1102/00578***...**2CT.csv',
'/****/**/******_1102/00578***...**3CT.csv',
 ...]
```

and what I want to do is group each path that contains the grouped values in the dict in the folder containing the key together.

I tried using for loops like this:

```
grpd_cts = []
   
for elem in tqdm(dict_list):
    temp1 = []
    for file in ct_paths:
        for key, val in elem.items():
            if (file[16:20] == key) and (any(x in file[21:26] for x in val)):
                temp1.append(file)

    grpd_cts.append(temp1)
```

but this takes around 30hours. is there a way to make it more efficient? any itertools function or something?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Loops of loops (you have at least 5) definitely get expensive fast, in any language! The best approaches involve trading space for time, and using techniques like hashing to avoid iteration where possible. e.g., transform your lists into sets and use intersection. Start on the inside: `(any(x in file[21:26] for x in val))` is your hot spot, since it's in the innermost loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ct_paths` is iterated repeatedly in your inner loop, and you're only interested in a little bit of it for testing purposes; pull that out and use it to index the rest of your data, as a dictionary.

What does make your problem complicated is that you're wanting to end up with the *original* list of filenames, so you need to construct a two-level dictionary where the values are lists of all originals grouped under those two keys.

```py
ct_path_index = {}
for f in ct_paths:
    ct_path_index.setdefault(f[16:20], {}).setdefault(f[21:26], []).append(f)

grpd_cts = []
for elem in tqdm(dict_list):
    temp1 = []
    for key, val in elem.items():
        d2 = ct_path_index.get(key)
        if d2:
            for v in val:
                v2 = d2.get(v)
                if v2:
                    temp1 += v2
    grpd_cts.append(temp1)
```

`ct_path_index` looks like this, using your data:

```py
{'1102': {'00575': ['/****/**/******_1102/00575***...**0CT.csv',
   '/****/**/******_1102/00575***...**1CT.csv',
   '/****/**/******_1102/00575***...**2CT.csv',
   '/****/**/******_1102/00575***...**3CT.csv',
   '/****/**/******_1102/00575***...**4CT.csv'],
  '00578': ['/****/**/******_1102/00578***...**1CT.csv',
   '/****/**/******_1102/00578***...**2CT.csv',
   '/****/**/******_1102/00578***...**3CT.csv']}}
```

The use of `setdefault` (which can be a little hard to understand the first time you see it) is important when building up collections of collections, and is very common in these kinds of cases:  it makes sure that the sub-collections are created on demand and then re-used for a given key.

Now, you've only got two nested loops; the inner checks are done using dictionary lookups, which are close to O(1).

Other optimizations would include turning the lists in `dict_list` into sets, which would be worthwhile if you made more than one pass through `dict_list`.